# S-function does not exist error in Simulink MATLAB

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to run a model in SImulink Matlab that uses both Matlab based S-function block (a .mexw32 file) and a C code based S-function block (a .c file). When I run the model, I get the error below:

```
Error in S-function 'Transformer/Practical characteristics to  biochemical composition  Waste1': S-Function 'GeneralADM1Transformer' does not exist
Component:Simulink | Category:Model error


Error in S-function 'Transformer/Practical characteristics to biochemical composition Waste2 ': S-Function 'GeneralADM1Transformer' does not exist
Component:Simulink | Category:Model error
```

I don't know why it keeps saying "It does not exist". The file is there, and it does exist. Someone should please help me out here.

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4U3v.png)

[The files arranged in a folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x9zb.png)

I downloaded and installed MATLAB support for MinGW-w64 C/C++ Compiler to compile the C code so that it can be called from MATLAB using MEX. I'm still getting the same error despite doing this. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: On a 64-bit windows machine, you should generate a mexw64 file: the one in your path is a mexw32 file. Did you compile that file yourself?

Comment: @picchiolu No, I didn't compile it myself. How do I generate a mexw64 file?

Comment: If the compiler is installed properly (i.e. after ```mex -setup``` in MATLAB), something like ```mex filename.c``` is usually enough. You need to check if you are on a 64-bit platform, though.

Comment: @picchiolu, I am on a 64-bit windows machine, and I've installed the compiler properly.  on entering `mex -setup`, it showed `MEX configured to use 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)' for C language compilation.`

So how do I convert the mexw32 file to 64? or how do I compile to 64?

Comment: you don't need to "convert": you simply compile on the 64-bit machine using the ```mex``` command.

Comment: Thank you @picchiolu! Works now after compiling